# iOS memory crash but memory usage seems low

Tags: ios, memory, crash, crash-reports

Our app is crashing due to memory, but the numbers don't make sense...

We follow the app with the XCode memory, Activity Monitor instrument and VM Monitor instrument, they all show relatively low memory usage (200-300 MB). Then the app crashes, without seeing any increase in memory. As we receive the memory error in XCode, memory usage still shows 200-300 MB.

Now, when we look in the crash log, the numbers also don't add up:

[image]

You can see that rpages is 166,401 (always the same number, I guess this is the per-process limit), but lifetime max is only 82,558 pages. What does this mean? How can the used pages be higher than the lifetime max? Any ideas on how to debug this, considering that everything seems fine right before the crash?

Edit: Entire log

```
Incident Identifier: 224F591A-4DAD-4E3B-94B0-7841F79DC939
CrashReporter Key:   2cdbe65d7adaca53c47419ec2a91fb865acf7752
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.3 (12F70)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Sun Mar 29 19:42:54 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2784.20.34~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T7000
Date:                2015-08-18 10:39:42 +0300
Time since snapshot: 153 ms

Free pages:                              14939
Active pages:                            98258
Inactive pages:                          36410
Speculative pages:                       3972
Throttled pages:                         0
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             43937
File-backed pages:                       50961
Anonymous pages:                         87679
Compressions:                            13469254
Decompressions:                          5264206
Compressor Size:                         59296
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        157628
Page Size:                               16384
Largest process:   swar

Processes
     Name       |            <UUID>                |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

           tipsd <ac746a1f2b6234279134a8ddae94b6fe>         0.032         226                0           -           764   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        recentsd <47bd382ae85b3fc8928ee5c749f82fd9>         0.480         466                0           -          1381   50                       (daemon) (idle)
 lsuseractivityd <8b2d13f5c3f2320eb2a4f76cec459d76>         1.475         465                0           -          1896   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   nanoregistryd <7b5314f368b334f490b9b5a4dc7d7b18>         0.948         515                0           -          1852   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            afcd <0495404ae525381dbeccebd20688a26d>         0.054         129                0           -           337   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         healthd <0a91b13bb79b340eac092805d49a8a4a>         4.712         680                0           -          1665   50                       (daemon) (idle)
           amfid <1da345782c1e3485955b8994f5a0d380>         0.379         166                0           -           724   50                       (daemon) (idle)
DuetHeuristic-BM <20f527867a0930bfa1cb1018f8deace4>         6.950         345                0           -           812   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    StocksWidget <34ffd44b6c453e16950714d45e428822>         1.513        1474                0           -          3141   50                       (suspended)
            awdd <1d6edd46b3ea3f0280f5364d39a31af6>         0.075         259                0           -           985   50                       (daemon) (idle)
WirelessRadioMan <8cfea3380d1d3e928bda2532eb06bc7e>         0.064         282                0           -           897   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            geod <92817fccef953baa9cdceafd4c7525ff>        23.703         744                0           -          1399   50                       (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Stream <fb9bd8e2b6fb3b3db4b19e36505994df>       384.461         178                0           -           687   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        profiled <d7fb0e3e5a913b8fa87c15f8c0a6b7bd>         1.971         526                0           -          1835   50                       (daemon) (idle)
containermanager <2711536b7f0937b297d0bbe967e75990>         7.924         320                0           -           826   50                       (daemon) (idle)
             pkd <dd1fe40eb69a3a8aa562894d48ff6e4c>         1.389         373                0           -           640   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        installd <e0d8a573ad3d3cca9079d8071cfb6f4f>        20.440         584                0           -          2227   50                       (daemon) (idle)
         assetsd <bae0a17845ad3f67ba1a411952fe110a>         0.451         646                0           -          1959   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      aosnotifyd <270321e35a5b3813a69005715d1e53ad>         4.120         296                0           -          1051   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   findmydeviced <4d9d7db245583abb8cc63048f47bc81d>         1.769         359                0           -          1230   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            swcd <21b30b48e2c23d2da451c486c81fd7fd>         0.098         168                0           -           519   50                       (daemon) (idle)
            bird <24998ba1f9cc3b0290bbe7a60e19ca8d>         0.808         349                0           -          1118   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        nehelper <8c4dd6ac8405393592f307ac25b40bc6>         0.773         238                0           -           718   50                       (daemon) (idle)
mobile_installat <539c48d34bbf38a990893658bdc35c9e>        10.021         333                0           -           894   50                       (daemon) (idle)
             atc <1786925dab253512afbbe190a809fde2>        16.176        1528                0           -          4310   50                       (daemon) (idle)
  mobactivationd <e4768d24f3b63a3b8dea47f98730e35d>         1.729         212                0           -           698   50                       (daemon) (idle)
streaming_zip_co <e3ca632324193e87a3bf813843db6996>       488.599         280                0           -           973   50                       (daemon) (idle)
assistant_servic <46edeb480a1c30f09b058aa0958382db>         5.329        1009                0           -          3493   50                       (daemon) (idle)
      assistantd <73bc187a9374301dbb7bcf1b4c6d2867>         5.631        1213                0           -          2076   50                       (daemon) (idle)
 gamecontrollerd <792b9aa8c6e03c66a222b695a46d2f5a>         0.033         256                0           -          1056   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        routined <2f5f98267fb639b19cc19de5c048bbe9>        17.483         650                0           -          1769   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       securityd <45745b7adb2330a0ba1c1c32c0501e80>        37.823         728                0           -          1428   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        sandboxd <841b9a4124be3a1ea60b2b8075283db1>         0.590         158                0           -           610   50                       (daemon) (idle)
        misagent <7be2720f415930c3af52d7b9b267b702>         2.200         656                0           -           399   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       coreduetd <a2d44574d75d3e87b97014747811328e>        83.155        1208                0           -          2277   50                       (daemon) (idle)
       accountsd <9edc4e6d313832bcaba2afd137da6f90>        13.491        1090                0           -          4070   50                       (daemon) (idle)
    mediaremoted <65a3c03147663dc790c80a060e6d1c17>         2.736         441                0           -          1769   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     pasteboardd <6f9aa8e941ce3e2893513205f5a73ca0>         0.024         125                0           -           420   50                       (daemon) (idle)
coresymbolicatio <028c280ccb6737688602e6f3203c66b9>         0.197         104                0           -           377   50                       (daemon) (idle)
     diagnosticd <ebb6f638b1b13aedabaaf9690bb18c62>         0.225         125                0           -           215   50                       (daemon) (idle)
   nsurlsessiond <6d55c4fc44fa3c96acf44cdaf58815b5>       176.461         686                0           -          1853   50                       (daemon)
            seld <bb0fbcebb3cd3f04a571df35ef3d5cb6>         1.246         254                0           -          1020   50                       (daemon)
            nfcd <f0e3498c9e253ceebc5f7c67b56717a5>         0.763         217                0           -           704   50                       (daemon)
           passd <be4bad55b2363eb39629c7891067105f>         6.577         743                0           -          2425   50                       (daemon)
    itunescloudd <991319c425033b0fb12ecc983bf74781>         1.664        1212                0           -          2556   50                       (daemon)
com.apple.dt.ins <ba8dcb4ceeb33a2b92ae58283ef393b3>        20.492         257                0           -           745   50                       (daemon)
            afcd <0495404ae525381dbeccebd20688a26d>         0.426         142                0           -           341   50                       (daemon)
 companion_proxy <05c4afee46a5377d9ca1bc14d07d76ae>         0.207         260                0           -           885   50                       (daemon)
notification_pro <21284498a1973ddf8dfc72d4835189a6>         0.647         144                0           -           444   50                       (daemon)
   biometrickitd <f32f0f5360623ec5b2f4d76718544027>         1.827         254                0           -           728   50                       (daemon)
     debugserver <adf18cd25921364198631aa0bfc40946>         0.034         144                0           -           414   50                       (daemon)
      MobileMail <5a8957c4d74f3e94873f7add08fc606b>         3.743        1952                0           -          4518   50                       (resume) (continuous)
             lsd <2f0b3813a37b31e0b37d0ba054bd6723>        16.210         511                0           -          1545   50                       (daemon)
            tccd <d966d737dd6c3686aed9b8310b475a94>         1.394         382                0           -           869   50                       (daemon)
             kbd <c01e51bbdd733ed6804968afb25d74b4>         6.440        1312                0           -          2931   50                       (daemon)
            swar <68f1bcb5b35430d0a16361d243ff19a1>        47.191      164353                0           -         75418  200  [per-process-limit]  (audio) (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <910f2f7edc493e8fbaac4fd689a179e8>         1.242         756                0           -          1933   50                       (daemon)
        BTServer <bbb2e7f408fd3c0b91c671db280bb4fd>         3.509         489                0           -          1760   50                       (daemon)
           wifid <d3d7d48d59a13235b6c4180f70b8bebd>        86.079         628                0           -          1784   50                       (daemon)
       lockdownd <83499bfcfbd93fbebf1fbe8b36ebae67>        59.743         350                0           -           979   50                       (daemon)
      discoveryd <ead6c2ea8a3c31849b09f2988a4b6279>       113.997         666                0           -          1413  100                       (daemon)
       locationd <195e79011afd327c91dc10ee6dd2d944>       962.308        3210                0           -          4575   50                       (daemon)
         syslogd <325431ec29e9358e9995898a8af11979>        84.495         249                0           -           401   50                       (daemon)
identityservices <6dda716fc3503fc2bd15c23c4b8fa50c>        15.329         863                0           -          2061   50                       (daemon)
         imagent <de0c095babad32698448900bda266890>        11.375         550                0           -          1508   50                       (daemon)
        cfprefsd <18d97c4dba8c3002a05a8ce85f6b16e0>        35.036         458                0           -           811   50                       (daemon)
    mediaserverd <b379cb48bc4f3a9b93be0a501f06eea4>       939.712        2102                0           -          4409   50                       (daemon)
   iaptransportd <72b3ef68b33a3e5ab584b919d6c111bb>        13.424         418                0           -          1339   50                       (daemon)
          powerd <81f6770902523cafaa3788f6457ad480>        34.075         291                0           -           540   50                       (daemon)
           timed <e4e07eafac283892a107fa150c3886b5>        89.524         449                0           -          1358   50                       (daemon)
            apsd <21d421c46a1c30969c70adb9056d3609>        26.262         773                0           -          2018   50                       (daemon)
        networkd <79274f337988346eaa6af3fadac635c4>        80.504         720                0           -          1741   50                       (daemon)
             vmd <cd05d8c9199038e79edb1d1f3c22e8ee>         0.121         454                0           -          2006   50                       (daemon)
     dataaccessd <9f9d3beb74123a42842a96eafa114b21>        22.728        1681                0           -          4138   50                       (daemon)
        sharingd <0ff12aa500f53a958a9fd1b51801d1aa>         2.610         744                0           -          2439   50                       (daemon)
         searchd <41b7b55fdc343454a64bebe5e6228fb7>         5.881        1049                0           -          3225   50                       (daemon)
    itunesstored <91589b72fbbe362a9533e256b4b10479>       102.327        2845                0           -          4314  100                       (daemon)
    syslog_relay <89bc831557c532a98d54277f6a11a5d3>         6.239         119                0           -           240   50                       (daemon)
     SpringBoard <dc9dbb9e6a6a3f41b8ed05a3daefa35b>      1266.942        7176                0         +23         16698   50                      
      backboardd <5e756a7f855435d3a213a3b23d3fb2e6>      6419.347       11314                0           -          4358   50                       (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <7a849d042cf23564b393016f82832ccd>       574.828        1186                0           -          2316  200                       (daemon)
       fseventsd <af7bd0467f083a3297af450e6e7d3e32>        18.810         332                0           -           713   50                       (daemon)
         configd <66e303bfd8dd366fac03bc9f132fbf48>        80.325         564                0           -          1472   50                       (daemon)
    fairplayd.H2 <1f809b2f4d683908bb01d9a8c46fafbe>         9.185         163                0           -          1442   50                       (daemon)
   wirelessproxd <60d34b5bd84339eeb3b0e9d40f657d08>         0.188         235                0           -           964   50                       (daemon)
      aggregated <f480a4d55fc23561913102f52b49cfbb>      1018.613        1346                0           -          2442   50                       (daemon)
      assertiond <f41737263bbe36be9cdb7aa4ef6cb94e>        13.476         346                0           -           954   50                       (daemon)
       distnoted <e485ac96b8b0303a866c9d97b5677d21>         2.883         203                0           -           325   50                       (daemon)
filecoordination <66d2f8c2520431a8ac3153ddcacf5f94>         4.018         290                0           -           926   50                       (daemon)
      DTMobileIS <53394376105337f4a56fd02b851940a7>       849.606       16945                0           -         50621   50                       (daemon)
       gputoolsd <e1972467611430818f1ad36f8c71a37e>         2.072         706                0           -          1670   50                       (daemon)
   nsurlstoraged <64561d059b9e32a68d79bea9c76a11ad>        44.223         885                0           -          1406   50                       (daemon)
      CommCenter <ebded28c16df39fa9918ef17e9c7f69f>       540.175        1519                0           -          4966   50                       (daemon)
         notifyd <5401847189ab3eb0af2a5c0c969ac3e7>        56.653         372                0           -           428   50                       (daemon)
     ReportCrash <52d16041a96631deb5552ff0582b5223>         0.282        5298                0           -         16642   50                       (daemon)

**End**
```

Comment: 200-300 mb is low memory usage?

Comment: I said "Relatively" :)
It's normal memory usage for our game, and the crash report shows 160,000 pages which is 600MB. The device has 1GB of memory, and our game doesn't crash even when we see 400+ MB.

Comment: Normal memory usage for any app ideally is below 100mb, irrespective of device. Please give the total log so that we can point out the exact cause of the crash

Comment: Added log to the original post. Thanks.